# javascript json.push add trash at char 1000

Tags: javascript, json, server

I have big json files in my server side ,
recently I saw in my json file a char of ... in position 1000 ( always at char 1000)

I've googled the issue and they pointed me to memory leak issue,
that javascript have limitation of 1000 char in one local parameter !!!!!

my question is how to override this issue ,
I will work with huge json file in my web site and I need to know how to properly deal with it ,

is there any way to deal with huge json file in javascript other than store it in local parameters

thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and observe what and how to [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). In case your question is about code, please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've done so far.

Comment: So, the json files on the server have ... at position 1000 ... how are these large json files created? clearly the problem is when the files are created.

Comment: my whole site is json based and I store a lot of info on it ,here is an example on the problem that I have , if you ran the below html file you'll see that in the output there is ... at position 1000                                                         <html><head></head><body>
<div style = "padding: 100px 100px 10px;">
      <script>
   var i=0;
   var jsonObj=[];
   var addJson=[{"id":"test","test":"test"}]
   for (i=0;i<1000 ; i++)
   {
    jsonObj.push(addJson);
   }
      prompt("test",JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
       </script>
</div></body></html>